# Joining conditionally in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, group-by, conditional-statements

I have a table called `USERS` and a table called `ADDRESSES`, as well as an `ADDRESS_TYPE` table. Each user can have multiple addresses.

```
SELECT *
FROM USER
INNER JOIN address ON address.userId = user.userId
INNER JOIN address_type ON address_type.id = address.addressType
WHERE addressType = 4 
    OR primaryAddress = 1
```

I want to join the address table to the user table if they have an addressType of 4, but if their addressType is NOT 4 it should pull in the address that is marked as the primary. Basically the problem is that I need to group the query so that each user only gets 1 row, while having logic = "if addressType = 4, join this address, else if primaryAddress = 1, join this other address".

Hope this makes sense, very grateful for any help.

Edit: These are the tables I am dealing with:

USER TABLE

+--------+-----------------+-----------------+
| userId | firstName       | lastName        |
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 10001  | Debbie          | Basson         |
| 10002  | Bamawama        | Kudon          |
| 10003  | JessicaM        | Stevies        |
| 10004  | Kinnon          | White          |
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+

ADDRESS TYPE
+----+------+-------------+------------+------------+
| id | code | description | modifiable | dataStatus |
+----+------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | HOME | Home        | 1          |          1 |
|  2 | BUSS | Business    | 1          |          1 |
|  3 | SCH  | School      | 1          |          1 |
|  4 | DON  | Donor Address    | 1          |          1 |
+----+------+-------------+------------+------------+

ADDRESS TABLE
+----------------+--------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+
| primaryAddress | userId | street1                 | city        | addressType |
+----------------+--------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+
|              0 | 10001  | 12660 Picarte Pl.       | San Diego   |           1 |
|              0 | 10001  | 446 W Wilshire Ave      | Fullerton   |           2 |
|              0 | 10001  | 4224 E. 114th Way       | Thornton    |           3 |
|              1 | 10001  | 828 Colorado Blvd.      | Los Angeles |           4 |
|              0 | 10002  | 40A Linden Ave., #2     | Somerville  |           1 |
|              0 | 10002  | 446 37th St., #2        | Oakland     |           null |
|              1 | 10002  | PO Box 06562            | Chicago     |           null |
|              0 | 10002  | 1281 W. 2nd St.         | San Pedro   |           null |
|              1 | 10003  | 10557 S. Oakley Ave.    | Chicago     |           null |
|              0 | 10003  | 1425 Harrison St., #324 | Oakland     |           null |
+----------------+--------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+

Comment: You are missing some information which is possibly best solved by showing us what your tables look like. (For example, in what table does `addressType` reside, and the same for `primaryAddress`. It might be possible to answer without this information, but it is making this an unnecessary puzzle for us

Comment: If you aren't going to have any changes to the ADDRESS_TYPE then you might want to consider putting the address type in ADDRESSES as an ENUM

Comment: is 'primaryAddress' located in 'address_type' table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT *
FROM USER
INNER JOIN address ON address.userId = user.userId
INNER JOIN address_type ON address_type.id = address.addressType
WHERE addressType = 4 
OR NOT EXISTS
(SELECT addressType FROM USER
 INNER JOIN address ON address.userID = user.userID
 INNER JOIN address_type ON address_type.id = address.addressType
 WHERE addressType = 4)
AND primaryAddress = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answer says, MySQL does support IF, but I have a feeling that's the wrong way to go in this case.   My sense is that left join is probably more appropriate.

I think this should get you half-way there, but I need to know where "this other address" comes from to finish the query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  user
LEFT JOIN
  address ON (address.userId = user.userId AND address.addressType = 4)
```

(ps. address_type table seems kinda redundant, so I'm skipping it in the join, but maybe it's important?)

Comment: I could be wrong, but the address returned here will never return a `primaryAddress=1` match, only rows which have `addressType=4`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has `IF` capabilities (and much more):

```
SELECT *,
       IF(addressType = 4, chosen_table.address_field_name, alternative_table.address_field_name) AS field_name
```

Replace `address_field_name` twice with the name of the address field. `chosen_table` is the "true" block of the `IF` and `alternative_table` is the "false" block.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like a UNION select?

Maybe like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM user, address, address_type 
WHERE address.userId = user.userId
AND address_type.id = address.addressType
AND addressType = 4 
UNION
SELECT *
FROM user, address, address_type 
WHERE address.userId = user.userId
AND address_type.id = address.addressType
AND primaryAddress = 1
```

Not sure if I got your table stucture right or not.. but the basic point is to try using the UNION statement :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would drop the ADDRESS_TYPE table and make your ADDRESS table a user address table, where you have enough columns to support 2 or 3 addresses.  This way you don't muck up your primary user table.

Nobody is going to need more then 2 addresses (with noted exception below).  You lose the the joins and the complexity, then you just need to have app logic to do what you want.  The way you have it designed, you make every action on these tables more complicated then if it was just one table.

The only way I could see the way you have described above is if this is some sort of app for business users where they could have several locations to ship to.